# Does adding a tag, redeem OP from explaining more context in code?

Tags: discussion, tags, questions

I've stumbled over [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31327474/opencv-c-suggest-method-or-fillter-to-use-or-idea) (and others of such kind before):

> hi guys i work on project detect on opencv and c++
>   and after weeks of search i get closed way i cant find good idea for my project
>   so i want some idea from u thats help me to complete my project
>
> > > i want to detect birds on sky
> > >       first i use color track its fail to track all birds and i notice when birds be far from camera its color change so the first method didnt help me 
> > >       i think detect birds its so easy but i didnt catch any way to do it
>
> there are no many object on sky for make failer project i want it 95% sucsess
>   for detect
>
> any ideas
>
> please dont vote unclear you can ask in comment if u dont understand 
>   if u dont have idea dont vote also

Should the OP expect to get this answered with some [opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencv) related answers, or getting some ready made [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)/[opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencv) related code?

Or is such question not asking for code at all, but opencv library concepts (why the c++ tag then?). I'm fairly not an opencv expert, so I actually can't judge, if such question could be answered easily, or at least concisely. But from my guts I'm feeling this won't be an appropriate on-topic quesiton, even not for the [opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencv) active community.

I'm always a bit unsure if additional tags that were put on the question (that aren't appearing in the question's body text explicitly) somehow improve regarding *implicit context*, and how such questions should be handled.

Well, my question(s) is(are), how does adding additional tags actually redeem an OP from

- posting a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?
- give an at least concise pseudo code sample?

---

To elaborate: I've been finding more *"sophisticated"* multiple tag combinations appearing with the [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) tag, like [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android), [cuda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cuda), etc. and these were nothing worth than actually obfuscating a simple, common [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) problem, or are simply too broad within the context setup with the tags applied.

Comment: The OP should at the very least answer some of the questions found within the comments and improve the question accordingly. At the moment it's simply poor. And tags don't really play a role there.

Comment: @Bart _"And tags don't really play a role there."_ That's exactly hitting the point I'm asking about here: Which role would tags play about such kind of questions.

Comment: @Bart Added the [tag:tags] tag. Does this inherently change the context of my question here, and could I expect some additional background automatically being implicit?

Answer (score 8):

There are a handful of valid scenarios in which an MCVE isn't necessary, but those are best evaluated on a case-by-case basis.  By and large, I've found it to be uncommon as opposed to rare, but there are valid questions that don't really need to have a compilable example to be answerable or well-understood.

This doesn't immediately mean that pseudocode is required, either; so long as the explanation of the problem is clear and concise, a question certainly *can* be answerable without either compilable code or pseudocode.  I stress though that this is a case-by-case evaluation, since  not all questions can be evaluated equally (and in select situations, code can help explain what the problem actually is as opposed to how it's perceived).

This doesn't mean that someone can ask broad questions with a smattering of tags just to get an answer, of course; if they're lacking an MCVE or pseudocode, they have to be *very clear* as to what they're asking.

Now, even though I don't lurk in C++ or OpenCV, this question is ***well*** below quality.  It's not asking for code, it's asking for ideas or inspiration - something along the lines of, "tell me what to do" or "help me out with this".

> ...i cant find good idea for my project so i want some idea from u thats help me to complete my project

At that instant, whatever tags are on the question *don't matter*.  The question needed to be closed ASAP.

Comment: _"The question needed to be closed ASAP."_ THX for backing up, that's what I did and thought from a 1st glance. It's just the tag specialization irritating me.

Comment: I don't pay the tags much attention until I've gotten through the body of the question.  Around that point I start to wonder if the tags made sense for the question, and if some of them didn't, that's when I move to edit them out.

Comment: _@Makoto_ _"I don't pay the tags much attention until I've gotten through the body of the question."_ Yeah, I'm doing so less and less (Even though I was intermittently notified by some tag expert users, I shouldn't jugde).